# Working with json and data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction.....I'm just starting out working with jSON and c# and have followed a tutorial (with a few hacks) to return some data back to a web page. What I currently have is this (abbreviated).

An asp.net solution which has a web-service that calls a stored procedure:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string ReadRegion()
    {
        DataSet myDS = getInterests();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DataTable myVenues = myDS.Tables[0];
        if (myVenues.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow myVenueRow in myVenues.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append(myVenueRow["descript"].ToString().TrimEnd() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("No Records Found");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

in this solution I also have an aspx page that has the following:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowRegionsInfo() {
        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/wsJQueryDBCall.asmx")%>'

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/ReadRegion",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessCall,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });
    }

    function OnSuccessCall(response) {
        $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(response.d);
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

The code is working as in I'm get a list of descript (ions) on the page. But going forward I want to include a series of rows in the returning recordset and ultimately I'd like to be able to filter the results on the fly from the client.

So my question is
Have I started out on the wrong foot ie. Am I returning the data back to the page in the correct format. Because all of the other jSon examples, to be honest, look different to mine! And if I am on the wrong foot could anybody give me some advice as to what steps I should be taking.

Thanks for any advice that comes my way!

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Setting `dataType: "json"` in your ajax options tells jQuery that you're expecting a JSON response from the server. You're just returning html from the server (which is the default), so remove that line.

Also, in your `OnSuccessCall()` method, you can change `response.d` to `response`.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowRegionsInfo() {
        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/wsJQueryDBCall.asmx")%>'

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/ReadRegion",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccessCall,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });
    }

    function OnSuccessCall(response) {
        $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(response);
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

I've removed that line but removing the response.d now returns no results.

Comment: Is the data actually being returned as a set of jSon data or is it just returning a string?

Answer (score 0):

> **If you call a specific method from an** ***aspx.cs*** ***file***

In ***aspx*** page use the following script

```
$('#<%= ddlItemCatogory.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            var catId = this.value;
            $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options[0] = new Option("loading ... ", "0");
            $("#phMainContent_ctl00_ddlItem").resetSS();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler/PopulateAjaxData.aspx/GetItem",
                data: "{'catId':'" + catId.toString() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select Item", "0");
                        $.each(data.d, function (index, item) {
                            $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options[$('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $('#<%= ddlItem.ClientID%>').get(0).options[0] = new Option("No Item found", "0");
                    }
                    $("#phMainContent_ctl00_ddlItem").resetSS();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed to load Item");
                }
            });
        });
```

The Code in ***PopulateAjaxData.aspx.cs*** is

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList GetItem(string catId)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        PopulateAjaxData item = new PopulateAjaxData();
        List<DataModels.Items> items = item.loadItem(int.Parse(catId));

        foreach (DataModels.Items i in items)
        {
            list.Add(new { Value = i.Id.ToString(), Display = i.Name });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

> If you call a ***aspx.cs*** file then use following code...

In .aspx page use the following code

```
  function addToCart() {
        var vehicleId = $('#<%= VehicleId.ClientID%>').val();
        var parameter = "vehicleId=" + vehicleId;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler/AddToCart.aspx?" + parameter,
            success: function (msg) {

                if (msg == "1") {
                    $('#message').html('Vehicle has been added to Cart.');
                }
                else {
                    $('#message').html('Vehicle can not be added at this moment.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

***aspx.cs*** load event use the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vehicleId = Request.Params["vehicleId"] ?? "";
    string productId = Request.Params["productId"] ?? "";
    string message = string.Empty;
    int CartId = 0;


    if (Request.Cookies["CartId"] == null)
    {
        if (CartId == 0)
        {
           DataModels.Cart cart = new DataModels.Cart();
           cart.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                cart = Service.Create(cart);
                if (cart.Id > 0)
                {
                    HttpCookie objCookie = new HttpCookie("CartId");
                    objCookie.Value = cart.Id.ToString();
                    objCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie);
                    CartId = cart.Id;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;
                Response.Write("-1");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CartId = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["CartId"].Value);
    }

    DataModels.CartItem cv_new = new DataModels.CartItem();
    if (CartId > 0 && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vehicleId)))
    {
        DataModels.CartItem cv = Service.ReadCartByVehicleId(CartId, int.Parse(vehicleId));

        if (cv == null)
        {
            cv_new.Cart = Service.ReadCart(CartId);
            cv_new.Vehicle = Service.ReadVehicle(int.Parse(vehicleId));
            cv_new.Product = null;
            cv_new = Service.Create(cv_new);
        }
    }
    else if (CartId > 0 && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(productId)))
    {
        DataModels.CartItem cv = Service.ReadCartByProductId(CartId, int.Parse(productId));

        if (cv == null)
        {
            cv_new.Cart = Service.ReadCart(CartId);
            cv_new.Vehicle = null;
            cv_new.Product = Service.ReadProduct(int.Parse(productId));
            cv_new = Service.Create(cv_new);
        }
    }


    Response.Write("1");
}
```